# how to separate text from integer

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have addresses:

```
ALKOŅU 3-20;
M.LUBŠNAS 16V-9;
STIEBRU 6-22;
ANDREJA UPĪĀA IELA 16-2;
MISNKAS 4 -115;
CISKADI,BAZNICAS 4;
```

How it is possible in sql to separate first text part (district) from integer (house and flat number)?

Comment: take a look at the string functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984%28v=sql.90%29.aspx. CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING will be your friends

Comment: @ralf - CHARINDEX doesn't cut it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the break-point is ALWAYS the first digit, then

```
SELECT RTRIM(LEFT(col, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', col + '0') -1)) as District,
       STUFF(col, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', col + '0') -1, '') as HouseAndFlat
FROM ...
```

e.g.

```
with t(col) as (
select
'ALKOŅU 3-20' union all select
'M.LUBŠNAS 16V-9' union all select
'STIEBRU 6-22' union all select
'ANDREJA UPĪĀA IELA 16-2' union all select
'MISNKAS 4 -115' union all select
'CISKADI,BAZNICAS 4')

SELECT RTRIM(LEFT(col, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', col + '0') -1)) as District,
       STUFF(col, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', col + '0') -1, '') as HouseAndFlat
FROM t
```